# Python sqlite select query with multiple parameters returns error message

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite table with 3 columns (id, username, password). There is 1 row in the table. I am trying to run a sqlite query to select the id where the username and password match what the user entered. My code for login.py is as follows:

```
import sqlite3 as lite


def login(userinput, userpass):
con = lite.connect('console.db')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username == :userinput & password == :userpass", {"userinput": userinput, "userpass": userpass})
    con.commit()
    row = cur.fetchone()
    print row[0]
```

my code for main.py is as follows:

```
import login
from getpass import getpass
import hashlib


username = raw_input("username >>")
password1 = getpass("password >>")
password1 = hashlib.sha224(password1).hexdigest()
login.login(username, password1)
```

I get the error message as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wip/PycharmProjects/console/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    login.login(username, password1)
  File "/home/wip/PycharmProjects/console/login.py", line 12, in login
    print row[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

My password that is stored in the table is stored using sha224 encryption, just as the user inputted password when prompted. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `fetchone()` returns `None` when no matching row is found.

Comment: If you print the password1 after hashing it, is it the same as the one stored in the database? The query seems not to return anything.

Comment: @mehtunguh I have checked my table multiple times. There is a row there and I am entering the correct data when prompted from main.py

Comment: @DJanssens it returns the same exact hash.

Comment: What if you print the query in your code, before executing it and querying it manually? Perhaps some nasty hidden symbol from the input is messing it up? Cause apart from that your query looks straight forward and correct.

Comment: @DJanssens I just tried this and am still getting the same error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not returning any rows, and `fetchone()` therefore returns None.

Try using `and` instead of `&` in your query:

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username == :userinput and password == :userpass", {"userinput": userinput, "userpass": userpass})
```

I don't think that `==` is normally valid SQL, so you should probably use `=` instead.

One other thing, you don't need to call `commit()` for a select query.

Comment: I just tried running this and it returns the same error message. Thank you for letting me know that you don't need to call commit() for a select query!

Comment: Well, the `&` is definitely a problem, and your query is definitely not returning any rows. You must be using the wrong username and/or password, or the password stored in your database is incorrect, or even perhaps the wrong database is being used.

Comment: Try executing  `cur.execute("select * from users").fetchall()` and see what comes back. Make sure that the values for the user name and the _hashed_ password match.